# How to deliver a matrix to a function that prints it?

Tags: c, function, pointers, matrix

I been asked to take a matrix of 4x5 and scan each row (that's why the for method) and then print the first half, and then teh second half.

I believe the problem isn't inside the function because they work fine on arrays

When it's trying to print I get random numbers and zeros -

```
0.000000
-107374176.000000
-107374176.000000
-107374176.000000
-107374176.000000
0.000000
-107374176.000000
-107374176.000000
-107374176.000000
-107374176.000000
0.000000
164582.031250
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
846674930930036512480361854271488.000000
0.000000
```

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void scanFloats(float** arr, int size); // scans the floats
void printFloats(float* arr, int size); // prints the floats

int main()
{
    float matrix[4][5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        scanFloats(matrix[i], 5);
    }

    printFloats(matrix, 10);
    printFloats(matrix + 10, 10);
}

void scanFloats(float** arr, int size)
{
    *arr = malloc(sizeof(float) * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Enter number\n");
        scanf("%f", (*arr) + i);
    }
}

void printFloats(float* arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", *(arr + i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use malloc the array is already allocated

Comment: Please compile with warnings: `foo.c:14:20: warning: passing argument 1 of 'scanFloats' from incompatible pointer type` ... `foo.c:5:6: note: expected 'float **' but argument is of type 'float *'`, same for the other funcs.

Comment: Think about this: What type is `matrix[i]`

Comment: I thought more on what it delivers. Matrix[i] will deliver the address+i which is what I wanted, to scan each row individualy.. How can I do it the right way?

Comment: I would say try `printFloats(&matrix[2][0], 10);`, but even then you're abusing an array by pretending it isn't two-dimensional

Comment: @adirk1 nah... `matrix[i]` is a pointer to an array. And your function is not expecting that

Answer (score 1):

Use same type as your array is:

```
void printFloats(size_t rows, size_t cols, float arr[rows][cols]);

int main(void)
{
    float matrix[4][5] = {
        {1,2,3,4,5},
        {10,20,30,40,50},
        {100,200,300,400,500},
        {1000,2000,3000,4000,5000},
    };

    printFloats( 4, 5, matrix);

}

void printFloats(sizet rows, size_t cols, float arr[rows][cols])
{
    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {

            printf("%8.2f", arr[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Same with scan function:

```
void scanFloats(size_t rows, size_t cols, float arr[rows][cols])
{

    for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            if(scanf("%f", &arr[r][c]) != 1)
            {
                 /* handle scan error */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/z8nxo1jhe

Comment: Nice answer. Unrelated: `scanf("%f", &arr[r][c]);` without any check is bad, Bad, BAD

Comment: @4386427 it is not real code only demonstration how to pass the array. It makes no sense to add anything else

Comment: Don't agree but UP anyway

Comment: Failure to check the value returned by `scanf` is an extremely common error.  Failing to demonstrate proper usage propagates the error.